# runOnUiThread prevent's TextView from marquee?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Suppose I have a `Fragment` with a `TextView` (let's call it TextView A) which contains a `String` of words, and another `TextView` (TextView B) which is a timer, getting updated by a handler like this...`mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);`.

The problem is whenever the `Handler` for `TextView` B gets updated every second, it prevents `TextView` A from running the `marquee animation`.

Here's the code I'm using to update `TextView` B...

```
public void updateTextViewB()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // Code that set's the constantly updating time

                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    thread.start();
}
```

What are the option's here to solve this? Should I set the focus to `TextView` A?

Comment: Is handler running on background thread or ui thread?

Comment: The ui thread, i'm assuming.

Comment: it is better to create a custom `textview` rather than the nested `run()`

Comment: How would i do this? And will it update on the ui without creating a new thread?

Comment: This code is extremely suspicious.  Why are you creating a `Thread`, and why are you then posting the `Thread` to a `Handler`?  Please include the code you omitted.  This could get worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and just solved it. If your TextView A and B are in the same layout then they are siblings, each time there is an update on the focus of any sibling (including A itself) the marquee animation restarts. Each time B is updated it requests the focus so A marquee animation restarts. Solution? All you need to do is put A in its own layout so it has no siblings, just one parent. Here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_b"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text being updated each second"
                />

    <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/marquee_text_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_b"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Long text with marquee animation that keeps running on the screen :P :)"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I know this post is old but, I'm actually having the problem without the two TextView's beeing sibblings...

A's grand grand parent is actually the same layout as B's grand parent tho...

any idea?

Comment: this workaorund is still working out. 2021